# Do Airbus aircraft have an "off" position for their landing gear?

Tags: landing-gear, hydraulic-system

I know some Boeing aircraft feature an up, down, and **"off"** position for their landing gear lever. I know that some Boeing wide-body jets do not have a 3rd lever position, but still have an "automatic" "off" setting that takes effect after a time-delay (which begins when the gear comes up). Do airbus, bombardier, embraer, etc. have a 3rd gear lever position in any of their aircraft? If not, do they have an "automatic" off setting?

Comment: "Off position" for the gear or off-position for the switch that controls the gear? Do you mean as in "gear up / off / gear down"? Please clarify in your original post.

Comment: What would "off" even mean?

Comment: @ratchetfreak We have [a question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/18951/62) on that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was working for Airbus before, never seen it on A300, A320, A330, A340, A380, A350 or A400M. Only Gear Up or Gear Down position.

For confirmation on A320, here the FCOM section:

> NORMAL OPERATION
>   The flight crew normally operates the landing gear by means of the lever on the center instrument panel. The LGCIUs control the sequencing of gear and doors electrically. One LGCIU controls one complete gear cycle, then switches over automatically to the other LGCIU at the completion of the retraction cycle. It also switches over in case of failure. The green hydraulic system actuates all gear and doors. When the aircraft is flying faster than 260 kt, a safety valve automatically cuts off hydraulic supply to the landing gear  system. Below 260 kt, the hydraulic supply remains cut off as long as the landing gear lever is up.
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: To summarize the FCOM, the system goes automatically to the equivalent of Boeing's OFF when airspeed exceeds 260 kts.

Comment: Im sorry for the unclear question. Regardless, it has been answered. Yes, what I meant was "gear up"/"off"/"gear down". According to the answer (much appreciated!) there is an automatic off position for the gear (hydraulic cutoff to gear over 260 knots). This is what I was looking for. I am sorry for writing an unclear question. Thank you Chris Lau!

Comment: This is **incorrect** for the A300. From the A320 onward, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** Airbus aircraft used to have an OFF position (called **NEUTRAL**) for the landing gear lever on the **A300 and A310**. As [Chris Lau's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/50498/33692) shows, this third position was removed on the A320 and all subsequent models. Note however that there is no NEUTRAL label next to the lever (where Boeing would write OFF):

> [image: Airbus A300 Landing Gear Lever]
>
> **(4) Landing Gear Normal Lever:**
>
> - **UP:** The L/G lever electronically controls the Green hydraulic supply for the L/G operation. The Green hydraulic system only is used for L/G retraction. When the lever is UP, the main wheels are automatically braked, during the L/G doors opening, through the ANTI SKID system, (the ANTI SKID selector being in NORM position) and without action on the brake pedals. L/G nose wheel is braked by a mechanical device.
> - **NEUTRAL:** When L/G lever is in the Neutral position, ANTI SKID system is deactivated and the L/G hydraulic pressure is cut off. Neutral position is normal flight position.
> - **DOWN:** When L/G lever is at DOWN the ANTI SKID system is operative.
>   Note: On ground, L/G lever can be moved from DOWN to Neutral position and vice versa, but interlocks prevent an inadvertent UP selection.

<sup>(Airbus A300 FCOM - Chapter 7 Landing Gear - Landing Gear Controls)</sup>

> [image: Airbus A310 Landing Gear Lever]
>
> **(1) Landing Gear Control Lever:**
>
> **UP:** The landing gear is retracted.
>
> - An interlock mechanism prevents unsafe retraction by locking the lever when gear position proximity detectors of selected SYS (1 or 2) are not in flight configuration:
>
>   - 3 shock absorbers extended
>   - nose wheel centered
>   - 2 bogie beams aligned.
> - During door opening only, anti skid is deactivated and main gear wheels are braked automatically.
> - At end of nose gear retraction travel, nose wheels are mechanically braked.
>
> **Neutral:** Normal flight position. Hydraulic pressure to landing gear circuit is cut off.
>
> **DOWN:** The landing gear is extended and the system remains pressurized.

<sup>([Airbus A310 FCOM - Landing Gear](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A310-Landing_Gear.html) - Controls: Landing Gear Lever Panel)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are only two positions in the Embraer E-Jet family. There is also a downlock release button (red) which mechanically bypasses the system protection logic. It should be used only in the event of a landing gear control lever failure or when it is necessary to clear obstacles.

[image: LG panel]